# FileStatus Object Block Size

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

As per the HDFS guide, for smaller file size hadoop does not allocated full block for storing file data over the data node. I am using FileStatus using java api to connect to fetch the metadata information associated with the file path. Below  mentioned is the code.

```
...
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://10.0.7.111:8020/"), conf);
iterator = fs.listFiles(new Path("/"), true);           
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                LocatedFileStatus status = iterator.next();             
                Path path = status.getPath();               
                System.out.println(path);
                FileStatus status1 = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path.toString()), conf).getFileStatus(path);
                System.out.println(status1.isDirectory());
                System.out.println(status1.isFile());
                System.out.println("Length " + status1.getLen());
                System.out.println(status1.getReplication());
                System.out.println("Block Size" + status1.getBlockSize());              
            }
...
```

I am expecting that block size will be of size of the file size but displaying 128 MB. Below mentioned is the output. Is my understanding in-correct ? Appreciate the response in advance.

```
File : hdfs://10.0.7.111:8020/t1/test1.txt
...
Length : 53
...
Block Size : 134217728
```

Answer (score 0):

Block size in Hadoop has very different meaning than what you might be used to when comparing to non-distributed filesystems we often use (HDFS, EXT3, FAT32 etc). You shouldn't worry at all about wasted space and block size as you would in other file systems.

Block size in HDFS only means this:
1) when storing file, HDFS will split file in blocks and store them on different machines to evenly distribute data over multiple machines

2) when reading one mapper task will be run per block allowing paralelisation when processing large files

BTW. reason you can query block size per file is that you can also set it per file, which is also very different when compared to commonly used filesystems.